# ifelse statement in mapply r

Tags: r, if-statement, mapply

I am using mapply to find the sum of a range of indices for all cases:

```
score = mapply(function(x, y, z) sum(df[x, y:z]), seq_len(nrow(df)), df$index, df$index+10)
```

How can I add a ifelse statement to mapply so that it only applies the function if df$index >5, else the sum is 0?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should probably work

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) if (y > 5) sum(df[x, y:z]) else 0, 
         seq_len(nrow(df)), df$index, df$index+10)
```

Or you could avoid `if`/`else` by multiplying by `(y > 5)` so `index > 5` would be multiplied by 1 (`TRUE`) giving `sum(df[x, y:z])` and `index <= 5` would be multiplied by 0 (`FALSE`) giving 0.

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) sum(df[x, y:z]) * (y > 5), 
        seq_len(nrow(df)), df$index, df$index+10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `ifelse` and it should work

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) ifelse(y > 5, sum(df[x, y:z]), 0), 
             seq_len(nrow(df)), df$index, df$index+10)
```

---

A better option would be pre-assign based on the 'index' value to 0 for those 'index' that are less than or equal to 5.  Should be more efficient

```
i1 <- df$index > 5
score[!i1] <- 0
score[i1] <- mapply(function(x, y, z) sum(df[x, y:z]),
                     seq_len(nrow(df))[i1], df$index[i1], df$index[i1] + 10)
```